# BaseExpandableListAdapter not Updating on DataChange

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

I'm using **BaseExpandableListAdapter** for my **ExpandibleListView**.The data get displayed properly for the first time of ExpandibleListView.setAdapter().I'm setting a new Adapter once again with single group with single child.On debug i observed,**getgroupCount()** is called and returned **count 1**. **getChildCount()** called and retuned **count 1**.But,**getGroupView()** and **getChildView()** are not called.

I tried different ways like invalidate(),invalidateViews() for ExpandibleListView; notifyDatasetChanged() for Adapter.Nothing worked out.

Thanks & Regards,
Sha.

Comment: Sorry guys,
Mistake from my side.I got to know some other view is using all space of screen pushing Expandible ListView to bottom of Screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys,
Mistake from my side.I got to know some other view is using all space of screen pushing Expandible ListView to bottom of Screen.

Regards,
Sha.